Freelance Video Editing music
Assalumualaikum,
I am a freelance who does video editing so as it is haram to use music in islam so if clients wants music and one of my friend adds the music and he sends the final product but i lend him some money  will my income be haram or halal?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the StackExchange model consider taking the tour] and checking our [help].
